# SQL SUM TOP 5 values per category then SUM category totals per ID

Tags: mysql, sql, sum

I'm trying to produce an SQL statement to SUM top 5 values within categories per userID to create an overall total. Is this possible and how do I achieve it? I can sum the top 5 per single category or ALL but struggling to see how I can SUM each separate category total together.

For example,

```
ID           Cater   Weight
--------------------------------
1            Cheese    10
2            Bacon     15
1            Cheese    5
2            Bacon     10
1            Cheese    22
2            Cheese    5
1            Bacon     10
1            Cheese    10
2            Cheese    5
1            Cheese    20
2            Bacon     10
1            Cheese    30
```

The results i'm looking for is,

```
ID      Total_Weight
-------------------
1            102    Top 5 Cheese (10+22+10+20+30) + Top 5 Bacon (10)
2            45     Top 5 Cheese (5+5) + Top 5 Bacon (15+10+10)
```

Any values outside of the Top 5 are ignored.

The code below displays the SUM of the top 5 weights from ALL categories AS total weight. Can I achieve what I want from a single statement?

```
$log = "SELECT id, cater,
    SUM(weight) AS total_weight
   FROM   (   SELECT id,
                 CASE WHEN @ID = ID THEN @ROW_NUMBER := @ROW_NUMBER + 1
                      ELSE @ROW_NUMBER := 1
                  END AS rn,
                 cater,
                 weight,
                 @id := id
            FROM individual,
                 (SELECT @ROW_NUMBER := 1, @ID := '') r
           ORDER
              BY
                 id, weight DESC
      ) TMP
 WHERE rn <= 5
   AND cater <> ''

   GROUP
BY id
 ORDER
BY total_weight DESC";
```

Comment: Something like [this article](http://www.artfulsoftware.com/infotree/qrytip.php?id=104) with SUM /GROUP in outer query.

Comment: Without a PRIMARY KEY, you don't really have a table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There might have some other better solution. But this will provide your expected result-

```
SELECT B.id, 
SUM(T_weight) Total_Weight,
group_concat(concat('TOP 5 ',B.cater,' (',B.T,')') SEPARATOR ' ') Details
FROM
(
    SELECT ID,cater,SUM(Weight) T_weight,group_concat(weight SEPARATOR '+') T
    FROM 
    (    
        SELECT *    FROM
        (
            SELECT id,cater, CASE WHEN @ID = ID THEN @ROW_NUMBER := @ROW_NUMBER + 1 ELSE @ROW_NUMBER := 1 END AS rn,weight,@id := id
            FROM your_table,(SELECT @ROW_NUMBER := 1, @ID := ''
        ) r
        WHERE cater = 'Cheese' ORDER BY id, weight DESC
        )A WHERE rn < 6


        UNION ALL

        SELECT *    FROM
        (
            SELECT id,cater, CASE WHEN @ID = ID THEN @ROW_NUMBER := @ROW_NUMBER + 1 ELSE @ROW_NUMBER := 1 END AS rn,weight,@id := id
            FROM your_table,(SELECT @ROW_NUMBER := 1, @ID := ''
        ) r
        WHERE cater = 'Bacon' ORDER BY id, weight DESC
        )A WHERE rn < 6


        UNION ALL

        SELECT *    FROM
        (
            SELECT id,cater, CASE WHEN @ID = ID THEN @ROW_NUMBER := @ROW_NUMBER + 1 ELSE @ROW_NUMBER := 1 END AS rn,weight,@id := id
            FROM your_table,(SELECT @ROW_NUMBER := 1, @ID := ''
        ) r
        WHERE cater = 'Cat3' ORDER BY id, weight DESC
        )A WHERE rn < 6


        UNION ALL

        SELECT *    FROM
        (
            SELECT id,cater, CASE WHEN @ID = ID THEN @ROW_NUMBER := @ROW_NUMBER + 1 ELSE @ROW_NUMBER := 1 END AS rn,weight,@id := id
            FROM your_table,(SELECT @ROW_NUMBER := 1, @ID := ''
        ) r
        WHERE cater = 'Cat4' ORDER BY id, weight DESC
        )A WHERE rn < 6


        UNION ALL

        SELECT *    FROM
        (
            SELECT id,cater, CASE WHEN @ID = ID THEN @ROW_NUMBER := @ROW_NUMBER + 1 ELSE @ROW_NUMBER := 1 END AS rn,weight,@id := id
            FROM your_table,(SELECT @ROW_NUMBER := 1, @ID := ''
        ) r
        WHERE cater = 'Cat5' ORDER BY id, weight DESC
        )A WHERE rn < 6


        UNION ALL

        SELECT *    FROM
        (
            SELECT id,cater, CASE WHEN @ID = ID THEN @ROW_NUMBER := @ROW_NUMBER + 1 ELSE @ROW_NUMBER := 1 END AS rn,weight,@id := id
            FROM your_table,(SELECT @ROW_NUMBER := 1, @ID := ''
        ) r
        WHERE cater = 'Cat6' ORDER BY id, weight DESC
        )A WHERE rn < 6
    )A
    GROUP BY ID,Cater
)B
group by id
```

The output is-

```
1   191 TOP 5 Cheese (10+22+20+10+30) TOP 5 Cat3 (25+9+20+16+13) TOP 5 Bacon (10)
2   45  TOP 5 Cheese (5+5) TOP 5 Bacon (15+10+10)
```

Comment: Thanks mate. I'll give that a go. Do I have to specify each category in that way? I have 6 category types. The 2 (Cheese and Bacon) were just examples.

Comment: Yes, I found no other way to make it Dynamic :(

Comment: Ok, thank you. Your code seems to work. Would it be possible for you to demonstrate how I would add more category's to the statement. i.e to reach my 6 category query. I'm still learning the construct of SQL.

Comment: Wait... Give me some time... I will be back.

Comment: Query updated. Just change the Cat names as per your original value. I have added a new category Cat3 under ID 1 and the output also contain new values. Please check the edited answer.

Comment: Perfect. Why when I remove a category does the total stay the same? i.e remove the 'N' off bacon and the ID total doesn't change but there is a value under that ID to be summed for that ID..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193505/discussion-between-mkrabbani-and-mark-harraway).

Comment: This works like a treat. Is it possible to add +1 to the ID total for every other entry outside of the top 5?

Comment: Therefore I will end up will the SUM of the TOP 5 per ID and all other Weights per ID are classed as having a value of 1 to give a Total_Weight.

Answer (score 0):

If you have MySql version 8 or higher, you can use this code:

```sql
  SELECT id, SUM (weight)
    FROM (SELECT test.*,
                 ROW_NUMBER ()
                     OVER (PARTITION BY id, categ ORDER BY weight DESC)
                     rn
            FROM test) sub
   WHERE sub.rn < 6
GROUP BY id;
```

You need MySql 8+ because I used the function row_number and only from version 8 it exists.
In the below fiddle example, I used Microsoft Sql Server 2017 because they didn't had MySql 8 or higher.

You can see your example [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/78d09/6).

[image]